# Help with Gauss-Bonnet Theorem Application

Tags: differential-geometry

I wish to use the Gauss-Bonnet theorem to calculate $\int_{M_r} K dA$ for the surface
$$M_r = \{ (x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 |z = \cos\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}, x^2 + y^2 < r^2, x,y, > 0 \}.$$
It feels natural to change to cylindrical coordinates $(\rho, \theta, z)$, so this is what I do. Namely, I set $x = \rho\cos \theta$, $y = \rho\cos\theta$ and $z = z$. Then
$$M_r = \{ (\rho,\theta,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 |z = \cos\rho, \rho < r, 0 < \theta < \pi/2 \}.$$

Then the surface looks like this (and forgive my terrible drawing skills):
[image]

The arrows indicate the direction I need to path-integrate in. The direction of the normal will be justified presently. This surface is a level set, so its normal is given by $N = \nabla(z - \cos\rho) = (\sin\rho, 0, 1)$. So the normal points as in the picture, namely 'up'.

I now wish to use
$$\int_{M_r}K dA = \sum \alpha_i - (n-2)\pi - \int k_g ds,$$
where the $\alpha_i$s denote the angles between the curves $\gamma$, $n$ the number of angles, and the final integral the path-integral of the geodesic curvature along the curves $\gamma$. So,
$$
\int_{M_r}K dA = \pi/2 - \int k_g ds
,$$
since all the angles are $\pi/2$.

Now, because of symmetry we have
$$
\int_{\gamma_1} k_g ds = -\int_{\gamma_3} k_g ds,
$$
and so we only need to parametrize $\gamma_2$. At $\gamma_2$ we have $r = \rho$ and so we may parametrize it by
$$\gamma_2(\theta) = (r, \theta, \cos r),$$
which clearly is an arclength-parametrization. Indeed, we have
$$
\gamma_2'(t) = (0, 1, 0), \\
\gamma_2''(t) = (0, 0, 0).
$$
Calculating the geodesic curvature is therefore easy, it's just $k_g = 0$. This is where I feel like I've made some mistake. It doesn't seem reasonable that the geodesic curvature along $\gamma_2$ is identically zero. If it is, the answer is just
$$\int_{M_r} = \pi/2,$$
independent on what value $r$ takes, which seems strange to me.

Answer (score 1):

You have not properly parametrized $\gamma_2$. Even if you use cylindrical coordinates, this does not mean you can map everything "to $(\rho,\theta,z)$ space".
From your drawing it should be clear that $\gamma_2$ is a circunference, not a straight line as your parametrization suggests!

The correct parametrization: at $\gamma_2$ you would have $\rho = r$ and thus $z=\cos r$, constant. The $x$ and $y$ coordinates on the curve can be parametrized in terms of $\theta$: $\gamma_2(\theta) = (r \cos\theta,r\sin\theta, \cos r)$. This is the curve that you need to calculate the geodesic curvature of.

Comment: I don't understand. $\gamma_2$ *is* a straight line in $(\rho, \theta, z)$. I did the same when calculating the normal, where I worked entirely in $(\rho, \theta, z)$.

Comment: That is the heart of the misconception: $\gamma_2$ is a straigh line in **coordinate space**, the piece of plane where your variables $\rho,\theta$ take values. You can parametrize your surface by these coordinates. In 3D space this curve is **far** from a straigh line, in exactly the same way that $M_r$ is very different from a flat portion of the plane.

I would suggest spending some time unraveling what coordinate charts on surfaces are, and how curves on the parameter space correspond to curves on the surface.

Comment: The normal calculation is also wrong. If you want to use cylindrical coordinates you cannot calculate the gradient how you are doing it. Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient#Cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates

Comment: I think I get it. Would you then also disagree with how I rewrote the surface $M_r$? Namely, I completely threw out $(x,y,z)$ and replaced it with $(\rho, \theta, z)$. The whole reason I switched to cylindrical coordinates, and into "$(\rho, \theta, z)$ space" is so that the part of the circle WOULD become a straight line.

Comment: If I am to be completely technically correct, then the equality $M_r = \{ (\rho,\theta,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 | \cdots \}$ is incorrect. The points are $(x,y,z)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and I understand $\rho,\theta,z$ as *functions* defined on $\mathbb{R}^3$. A way to fix this would be to write,
$M_r = \{ (x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 | cos \rho(x,y,z) = z, \rho(x,y,z) < r, \theta(x,y,z) < \pi/2 \}$.

Comment: The whole reason behind not being able to "translate into $(\rho,\theta,z)$-space" is not because of some arbitrary notion: you are implicitly setting up a diffeomorphism that does not preserve angles, distances, etc... and thus "doing geometry in parameter space" requires understanding precisely the relationship between **what you have in $\mathbb{R}^3$** and **what parameters you are using to describe it**.